# How can I strict my extrinsic to be executed only by Multisig user?

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, multisig

I have an extrinsic, which can be executed only by sudo. I want it to be executed only by MultiSig user.

I couldn't find way to do this.

I can replace `ensure_root(origin)` with `ensure_signed(origin)` and then it can be executed by both normal user and multisig user as well. I don't want normal user to execute this extrinsic.

Can someone please help me to provide the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask the user to provide the multisig data.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/3bc3742d5c0c5269353d7809d9f8f91104a93273/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L525

```rs
let account_id = ensure_signed(origin);
let multisig_account_id = multi_account_id(&signatories, threshold);

ensure!(account_id == multisig_account_id, <Error<T>>::NotMultisigAccount);
```