# is it possible to have a multisig root user?

Tags: substrate-node-template, multisig

Few days ago, I asked a question here [How can I strict my extrinsic to be executed only by Multisig user?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7200/how-can-i-strict-my-extrinsic-to-be-executed-only-by-multisig-user/7201#7201) to allow extrinsic to be executed only by multisig user. I got the solution. But it leads to another problem. Now any multisig user can execute the extrinsic.

I want only specific multisig user to execute this extrinsic. It's kind of multisig root user.

The purpose behind this requirement is that we have an extrinsic which can only be executed by sudo. We have 2 investors who also want to control this. Our plan is include these user investors with sudo so that when sudo initiates the transaction, it also needs 2 other approvals to execute the transaction.

Please let me know if it is possible to have multisig root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you don't need the previous solution anymore.

Just use pallet-sudo + pallet-multisig.

Create the multisig account. (you + 2 investors)

Set the multisig address as the sudo key.

---

e.g. Use the multisig account to send a runtime upgrade extrinsic.

[image]

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this answer. You solved my issue without making any code chance. Previous solution is still knowledgeful  